# Using google doc in an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios4, google-docs, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for a way to integrate Google Docs in an iPhone app (basically, I want to write something in a spreadsheet).

I look'd in the Google API's page dedicated for mobiles (http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/mobile/more/#google-all), and I was unable to find out how to connect to google docs.

I found a project, Google Docs Cocoa Sample (http://code.google.com/p/googledocs-cocoa-sample/), but it doesn't compile w/ iOS 4.2.

Have you any source code related ?

Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/fuellog/source/browse/branches/fle-3.5/Classes/FilesViewController.m?r=98) is some working code (with lots of room for improvement, I admit). It connects to Google and will extract data from a online spreadsheet. 
In importCar a CSV file is read from GoogleDocs.

I am not at my development machine right now, and don't remember the version of the Google API I use, but IIRC the code compiles against version 1.7.

Export and authentication is in LoginViewController.

Comment: I have downloaded the list from google doc. Now from the list I have, need to download the file from the google docs file list. Can you please help me how to do this in iPhone application?